# Can I use the Gemalto Citerion as an I2C slave?

Tags: java, java-me, i2c, gemalto

I have got the Gemalto Citerion concept board to work with the GSM capability. Looking through their Java Doc and the I2C methods, it seems you can only set the chip as a master.

Where as I am planning to use this board to abstract the GSM and internet capability. To do this it needs to be able to wait for commands from another board. I was thinking being an i2c slave would be a good way to do that; waiting for messages from the other (master) board.

Have I missed something in the javadoc from gemalto or is there no way to set this chip as a slave?